# How to stop long text from widening button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` containing some simple text buttons. In each button I set `layout_width` to `wrap_content` and `layout_weight` to `1`, so that they would divide the space in the `LinearLayout` equally. The text is dynamically changed, so I set `ellipsize` to `end` allow long text to be ellipsized, but instead it changes the button widths.

I can't specify a numeric button width because the `LinearLayout` width is the screen width. How do I get the layout manager to set the button width independent of the contents of the button, and let `ellipsize` deal with the possible overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For weights to work properly, you need to set the weighted dimension to **0dp**, not `wrap_content`.
I.e.: `layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: I believe `layout_width="fill_parent"` works as well.

Comment: Thanks. I was unclear about the meaning of wrap_content.

Comment: `wrap_content` basically means the width or height is set only to what it needs to be in order to fit and no more.

Comment: @JaredPrice `fill_parent` is deprecated since API 8 and has been replaced (renamed) to `match_parent`, just for your information